# White screen (distorted screen) after sleep mode,or after i block the phone

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an ionic cordova app which runs only in landscape mode.Splash screen appear good,but after the app is loaded,if phone enter in sleep mode or if I lock the phone,an white screen appear on half of the screen.This happend when i turn on screen for 1 second. I think the problem is because after i turn on screen the app appear in portrait mode,and while the screen is rotated to landscape mode appear that white screen.
In config.xml i have this :

The problem is only in android , on IOS works perfect.
Can someoane tell me which is the problem.
Txh